# Abstract Factory, Dependency Injection and good Design

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I am trying to get the knack of good system design. As there is no hard and fast rules for good system design, I request you to give me some valuable suggestions. I prepared an imaginary system and prepared a design for that. Please let me know if you think if this design is good or bad. Is there a better way? I used Abstract Factory and Dependency Injection in the solution.

Problem:

Design a system which runs in cars and controls it. The requirement is to make a system for Volkswagen Golf controlling components like engine, electrical, gearbox etc.

There can be different versions of Golf like BlueMotion, Twist, GT etc which uses different components. For example if GT uses engine a and electrical b, BlueMotion can use engine c and electrical d.

The engines, electricals and other components in different cars could be similiar, or could be completely different. For example a "Flat 4 CRDI" Engine uses CRDI technology for fuel injection and have a certain behaviour to reduce vibration. A "PumpeDuse V6" engine uses PD injection and its own method for reducing vibration which is completely different from "Flat4 CRDI". The difference is not only in the handling the vibrations but also most of the aspects of Engine behaviour.

As of now, the system model should handle the starting of Engine. Starting the engine means use power from the electrical system and crank the engine and keep idling. To start with, make a Golf "GT" with "Pumpe Duse E250" Engine and "BoschR10" Electrical system. However, many different series could be launched in the future and system should be able to extend the functionality and car models with minimal trouble.

Update: Code edited as per suggestions.

Code:

```
class Electrical
{
public:
    virtual void OpenCircuit() = 0;
};

class Engine
{
public:
    virtual void Crank(Electrical *) = 0;
};

class CarComponentFactory
{
public:
    virtual Engine* CreateEngine()=0;
    virtual Electrical* CreateElectrical()=0;
};

class PumpeDuseE250:public Engine
{
    virtual void Crank(Electrical *pEle)
    {
        pEle->OpenCircuit();
        //Do the crank
    }
};

class BoschR10: public Electrical
{
    virtual void OpenCircuit()
    {
        //Open the Circuit
    }
};

class GTFactory:public CarComponentFactory
{
public:
    virtual Engine* CreateEngine()
    {
        return new PumpeDuseE250();
    }

    virtual Electrical* CreateElectrical()
    {
        return new BoschR10();
    }
};

class VWGolf
{
    auto_ptr<Engine> mpEngine;
    auto_ptr<Electrical> mpElectrical;      
public:
    VWGolf(Engine *pEngine, Electrical *pElectrical):mpEngine(pEngine), mpElectrical(pElectrical)
    {
    }

    void Start()
    {
        mpEngine->Crank(mpElectrical.get());
    }

    ~VWGolf()
    {           
    }
};
```

Example for Creating Objects:

```
void main()
{
    GTFactory Factory;
    VWGolf golfGT(Factory.CreateEngine(), Factory.CreateElectrical());
    golfGT.Start();
}
```

Note that the names like "BoschR10" are imaginary.

Comment: I don't know how useful this is, but I'd really start by finding a realistic use case. All those made-up examples like modelling cars and animals just encourage you to attempt to model **everything**. The only way to achieve good design is to model only that which needs modelling. In real-world cases, that's fairly easy. But when modelling make-pretend cars, where do you stop? Should I model each wheel separately? What about the doors? Engine power? Car radio? And so on.

Comment: There are a million details in a car that you *could* model explicitly, or you could pretend they don't exist. And making *that* decision is what gives you a good design. Correctly determining what *needs to be in your model at all*, and what should just be left out. And that is why made-up examples like this always just lead to a big soup of inheritance hierarchies, rather than a (good) design.

Comment: Why do so many functions need to be virtual? Could some of the polymorphism benefit from being implemented with templates? Do you need separate classes for the different engine types? Could they be implemented as a single class that is just initialized differently? Probably, but it is impossible to tell, because it's a made-up example and so it is missing all the context you need to answer these questions. Until you know what these car classes are *for*, there's no reason to write more than this: `struct Car {}; Car vwGolf;` to define and instantiate a car. Beyond that it depends on context

Comment: @jalf. I thought making the problem simple and well known can lead to a common opinion, hence opted cars. IMHO,  a real world use case could get long and lead to more different opinions. The problem actually tells about what to be there in the model. The car contains just an engine and electrical, we can avoid the other components. However, I need to explain what assumptions I made by modelling this.

Comment: Assumptions:In the future the system need to handle different Series of Golf. For example a "BlueMotion" series with "CRDIFlat4" engine and "DelphiE45" electrical system. In this case I can inherit CRDIFlat4 from Engine(abstract base) and DelphiE45 from Electrical. A factory class called BlueMotionFactory will be inherited from CarComponentFactory. So I can just say VWGolf golfBlueMotion(new BlueMotionFactory()); golfBlueMotion.Start(); I cannot see how can we avoid inheritance hierarchies and virtual functions here. Note that the new Engine and Electrical are completely different.

Comment: So, yes we need separate classes for Engine as Engines can be completely different. As there is no code reuse here there is no scope for templates. All I am trying is making the model which easily extendible and the reader friendly.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why you need separate Engine classes. Why not one engine class that I can parametrize in the constructor? Don't all engines have the same properties (max speed, acceleration, fuel efficiency and so on)? The point I'm trying to make is that you're basically building a house out of legos, and then looking at that house and saying "so what can I learn about houses from this?" and the answer is *nothing* because the model contains nothing that you didn't put there yourself, nothing you don't already know.

Comment: And like I said, the keyword is **context**. Cars can be modelled in many different ways, *depending on what the purpose of the model is*. And you don't have that context because you're building your own little house out of legos, rather than looking at "so what does it take to make something that works in *reality*. You have no way to ask (or answer) all the tough questions that good design depends on, because these questions all related to the context in which the model is going to be used.

Comment: And explaining the assumptions you made when coming up with the scenario is pointless. What's interesting is the assumptions to be made when **designing the system**. The question needs to tell us *what is this for*, and then the answers can make assumptions based on this, and design a system based on those assumptions.

Comment: @jalf. I edited the original post with more information about the problem. The components can be completely different. Yes, max speed and acceleration could be properties of all engines. But, apart from these properties the behaviour of the engines is completely different. In short, the similarities are negligible.

Comment: @Jimmy: it still doesn't really answer my objection though. My point is that you're not going to learn anything about good design until you apply it to a problem you didn't just make up for the sake of being designed. **how** can the behavior of the engines be different? They're engines! They have an input telling them how fast you want them to go, and then they make little wheels turn as an output. The *parameters* are different, but the behavior is **exactly** the same. You're still going about this the wrong way.

Comment: You're trying to come up with a designable problem, and then designing it, which is **never** going to teach you anything new. Just like you're not going to get better at computing square roots if you start by a known square ("I want something that's suitable for computing square roots, so let's take 4 squared. That's 16. Hmm, I wonder what the square root of that might be"). You're trying to design the problem, rather than the solution. When you custom-fit every part of the problem just to answer my criticisms, you're turning the whole thing on its head.

Comment: Yes, it'll be more complex when you world with real-world scenarios (but it doesn't have to be much *more* complex), but it also has oen important attribute: it becomes designable! it gives you criteria to guide and evaluate your design. Your entire question **is** the design: You're saying exactly how the code should be structured. if you want to discuss good design, you have to start with a problem, not "I want code that looks like this and behaves like that", because that **is** basically the design.

Comment: @jalf. Edited the problem again. Now, I hope there is enough information to design a solution. My intention is to find out if there is any shortcomings in my basic understanding of system design. If someone think of a system like that how will they design it and how different it would be from mine. And the problem is still close to "real world"(a software system to control car components-initially it controls only the way to start a car-with an engine and electrical). Model it like class Car{} is not fair. Is it too hard to think Engine and Electrical as two classes?

Comment: @Jimmy: no, it's very easy to think of them as two classes. But it's hard to come up with a good design without asking **why** should they be two classes. You're still missing the point. The problem is in this sentence: "Design a system which runs in cars": a lot of systems run in cars. Many of them run an mp3 player, in addition to control logic for the heating in the seats, and a million other things. In order to design a software system, you need to know what the system **does**. And you still haven't answered that.

Comment: You've said that the system has to be able to start the engine, but what does that mean? Where is the requirement that starting the engine *has an effect*? As it stands now, this line will "start the engine just fine: `// now start the engine`. Software design is about the processes, the task that you want to accomplish. And you still don't haven't defined this task. The car can't be modelled until we know what the model is going to be used *for*. Is it for physics simulation so we can analyze fuel efficiency? Is it for a racing game? Or is it to allow software to drive an actual car?

Comment: Depending on the answer to *that* question, something as simple as "starting the engine" may imply entirely different things. Again, it is the processes that are important: what process do we want to model when the engine starts? The combustion of chemical fuel and the physical impulses that eventually drive the car? Or should the process start updating the position of the car in the game world? if the problem was something like "design the representation of a car in a racing game", it would be answerable. We'd have a clear idea of what we're trying to *achieve*, what *process* we're modelling

Comment: A car in a racing game isn't just a "model of a car". It is a model of the *process* of moving around the track: given information about the track we're driving on, the properties of the car, and the current input from the player, we want to feed this into a process whose result is to bring the car into a new state (different speed and heading, different position on the track, for example). This gives us a context for our design.

Comment: does my point make better sense now? :)

Comment: @jalf. Yes, I got your point before itself. It is true that I didn't give a proper requirement specification. My issue is the requirement specification is not the heart of the matter. By the reading the question and my solution, it is evident that I am trying to model a system which runs in a car and controls different components of it. Which game needs an object of electrical to crank an engine? Or, is there any need of cranking an engine for starting a car in a game?

Comment: The statement "Design a system which runs in car" coupled with the actual design I provided can give a clear picture about the system. And I provided what I need also-just an engine and electrical. Now, we are way far from the actual problem because of an inferior requirement specification.

Comment: I didn't give the actual process of starting an engine, but gave something which is sufficient to model the system-THE PROCESSES ARE DIFFERENT IN DIFFERENT ENGINES.

Comment: You made some valid points, and I appreciate that. The only thing is, I didn't get an answer from you for my original question. I think you have the ability to answer my question and actually understand the question, but your focus actually went elsewhere. Again the problem is not to design the class of birds and penguins, it is pretty much a real world software system.

Comment: yes, I understand the question. I just don't think it is answerable as it stands now (otherwise I would answer). Of course the processes are different in different engines, but how is this relevant to the design? Without knowing this, it is impossible to *create* a meaningful design. What kind of internal engine processes is the design going to have to represent? That directly influences how the engine should be represented (and how many classes should exist) You saying that you want multiple engine classes just means that you've already designed the system, which means we can't also do so.

Comment: Ok, I'll stop now. The amount of comments here is just getting silly. ;) If you're interested, I just wrote this ( http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/11/good-design-oop/ ) to try to clarify a few things, but other than that, it doesn't seem like I'll be able to contribute much more to the question as it stands. Thanks for your patience. :)

Comment: thanks jalf, I will have a look into your blog.

Comment: @Jimmy: You have actually answered your question in the comment on Nov 6th at 20:36: You provide a question: "Design a system which runs a car", and then you provide a result of the design. Asking to validate it, as @jalf said, without context is... well, just "missing the forest for the trees". Given a problem "Perform a mathematical operation", and an implementation `x * 2`, is the implementation correct? Well, it depends what the operation is meant to do, just as the design can only be validated when you know what you want to apply it for. As you say, it would not make sense for a game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd remove the dependency between factories (actually apply dependency injection) and VWGolf and I'd make sure to be using RAII instead of raw pointers.  You're main should look more like so:

```
void main() // still not applying RAII
{
  GTFactory factory;
  VWGolf golfGT(factory.CreateEngine(), factory.CreateElectrical());
  golfGT.Start();
}
```

Count how many mocks you'd have to make in order to test VWGolf with your way vs. mine.

Comment: @Noah, I can see removing the factory from VWGolf could be theoretically advantageous. But, you can now make golfs with different factories. For example, for a specific car you can create engine from GTFactory and create electrical from BlueMotionFactory. Is that acceptable? I haven't done mock tests yet, so I will do some reading and get back to you.

Comment: It's not only acceptable, but could very well end up being a future change.  Should the customer say, "We now have a new car that uses the GT engine and the BM electrical," you could respond in two ways: 1) reuse the GT and BM factories; or 2) make a new factory that either uses the others or has the same code.  I prefer option 1 for two reasons: 1) it's less work and more in line with reuse and OCP; and 2) it looks more like the requirement statement that caused the change (I like my code to resemble the domain whenever possible).  ...

Comment: Yeah, it's a small nit and pretty much pure theory but that's the kind of question asked, no?  In production code it would be one of those things that I'd say, "Well, it's not perfect but it's certainly good enough."  But there ARE practical concerns behind all "theory" considerations.

Comment: The mock thing goes like so...  You want to test each unit on its own in a controlled environment.  Doing this entirely 'correctly' requires the use of mocks.  If you're testing the VWGolf class you make a testing engine and a testing electrical (assuming VWGolf actually does something with these objects in Start()).  If you keep the factory parameter, I build my dependencies myself, method that you've got here then you also need a testing factory.  Seems again like a small nit but again there are practical concerns behind all theory.  It's sometimes hard to see the effects in small examples.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it again, I'd only just come up with the idea of wrapping the GT and BM factories into a new factory and hadn't given it enough thought.  I'd probably do that.  I would still remove the dependency because objects building their dependencies is something that smells to me and it reduces dependencies.  I don't know that it would happen but I should be able to build the object without the factory, and I could if the interface didn't artificially require factories.  The main objection I have is that the dependency between VWGolf and factories is not needed, so I'd lose it.

Comment: @Noah, I agree the rational behind removing the factory from VWGolf. However, I won't reuse the GT factory and BM factory for a new car. I think I will go for a new factory which has the same code. Because, GT and BM are two different models and there is no need to tightly couple an engine to either one. Only the BM Factory can return a "CRDIFlat5" engine looks not right to me. This can be subjective as a car owner can say BM Engine, but a VW Automobile engineer would say "CRDIFlat5". And from whose perspective we will see the domain? I think the engineer's in this case.

Comment: Well, code duplication is a smell so I'd tend to avoid it.  There can be legitimate reasons for such but without a clear understanding of the problem it's hard to tell.  With little hypothetical snippets like yours it can be hard to narrow down exactly what should be done because you are rather stuck with JUST theory.  But yes, how the domain would shape the design and when/where would certainly be different from different perspectives and it's at this point that theory tends to not say very much.  It's a judgment call.

Comment: @Noah, thank you. I changed my model as per your suggestions. Also, changed the original post with the new model.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I'd do:

start with the basics:

```
class Car {};
```

and then extend on it as needed.

The thing is, so far, there are no further requirements.
There is no requirement that the car *uses* the different components for anything, so I leave them out for now. We just have to be able to create a car with specific components. But until we know what these components are supposed to *do*, there's no reason to make them anything more than a comment:

```
// create a car using engine A and gearbox B
Car car1;

// create one with engine C and electrical D
Car car2;
```

And there we are. This is my design. Given this starting point, it takes very little code to extend the system when you come up with more requirements. There is virtually nothing that can break, or require rewrites when the requirements change. It is simple and clean.

So for now, I conclude that this is the ideal design matching your requirements. It is far more robust, far more efficient and far less likely to contain bugs than your big inheritance hierarchy. And it is one hundred percent reusable code too.

As you've probably gathered from my comments under your question, good design depends on context. There is no good design for "cars" in the abstract.

But we can come up with good designs for "cars for a racing game", or "a system for managing a car factory", or for "displaying the status of various properties of a car (doors open or closed, current speed, fuel level, unfastened seatbelts)."

The design doesn't depend on what **objects** you're modelling, but on **what you want to do with them**. And from your description so far, the purpose of the objects is nothing, except to be there. So I suggest a model where the cars *are there* and nothing else.

The best design is not the one that best describes some physical object, but the one that best allows your application to do what it is supposed to do.

And if all your application is supposed to do is "have a car", then the model becomes pretty simple.

Comment: Brilliant, in theory. But, he actually *does* have requirements.  ;)

Comment: @Johann, FYI, I edited the original post recently. You might not have seen the original post based on which jalf gave the answer. Initially, I didn't explain the problem well and expect the reader to understand the context from the code.

Comment: @Johann: the original "problem", which I answered, had no requirements, other than "I want to model a car, with certain components, and it should be extensible".

Comment: Sorry about that - I didn't realize that the answer and question got out of sync.

Comment: @joh By the way, even as it stands now, I still don't think there are any requirements. What you have is half a design. But there is still no problem we have to solve. You've said what classes you want, and what functions they should have, which is what the design is supposed to do. What the **problem** is supposed to do is simply telling us what purpose the program should serve. Then the **design** should come up with the classes, the functions, the names and all those specifics.So given that the problem is still nonexistent, I'd say my (nonexistent) design fits the bill even after the edits.